# Troubleshooting AWS EC2 instance reboot

Tags: reboot, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The company I work with has an AWS EC2 machine which has rebooted yesterday.

I looked at various files in /var/log, but didn't find anything which could give reasons as to why or who has rebooted the instance.

When I look at system.journal file, I found that between the last message before the reboot and the first message after the reboot there is an 10 minutes gap.

How should I go about further investigation ? Any tips on using CloudWatch or CloudTrail would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AWS can reboot EC2 instance for any number of reasons as mentioned [here](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-automatic-reboot-cause)

> - The instance failed one or both of its status checks.
> - The underlying hardware hosting your instance was faulty and Amazon EC2
>   restarted the instance to move it to new, healthy hardware.
> - Scheduled maintenance occurred on your instance that required a reboot.
> - A user or application inside your server rebooted the instance.

The linked post also talks about using CloudTrail to determine what caused the reboot. You're unlikely to find anything in CloudWatch (unless you're forwarding logs to CloudWatch)